# how to create page at server from android

Tags: android, drupal

Here I want to `post idea` to the `drupal` server from `android`.
For this I have no exact Idea, but I have trid so far below.

I am tried for the post the `title` and `body`.I am converting the title and body into the `json` format and pass to the server. I   tried for post the `individual title and body`  or `combine title & body`

when add **indivisual title & body**:

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type","page"));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title",title));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body",jsonnode.toString()));

                         // jsonnode value is {"und":[{"value":"body value"}]}

         System.out.println("value of the params =============> "+params);
```

Give me `status code 401`

```
I/System.out(  524): @@@@@@2    jsonnode=======>{"und":[{"value":"body value"}]}
I/System.out(  524): value of the combine node=======>{"type":"article","body":{"und":[{"value":"body value"}]},"title":"title"}
I/System.out(  524): value of the params =============> [type=page, title=title, body={"und":[{"value":"body value"}]}]
W/DefaultRequestDirector(  524): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
I/System.out(  524): =========> statusCode post idea=====> 401
```

**combine Title & Body :**

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("node",json.toString()));   
                        //  json value is  {"type":"article","body":{"und":[{"value":"body"}]},"title":"title"}

            System.out.println("value of the params =============> "+params);
```

Give me `status code 406`

```
I/System.out(  571): @@@@@@2    jsonnode=======>{"und":[{"value":"body"}]}
I/System.out(  571): value of the combine node=======>{"type":"article","body":{"und":[{"value":"body"}]},"title":"title"}
I/System.out(  571): value of the params =============> [node={"type":"article","body":{"und":[{"value":"body"}]},"title":"title"}]
I/System.out(  571): =========> statusCode post idea=====> 406
```

Httpconnection:

```
public static String makeWebForPostIdea(String url, String title,String body)
    {
        JSONStringer jsonobject = null;
        JSONObject json = null;
        JSONObject jsonnode = null;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonvalue = new JSONObject();
            jsonvalue.put("value", body.toString());

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            array.put(jsonvalue);

            jsonnode = new JSONObject();
            jsonnode.put("und", array);

            System.out.println("@@@@@@2    jsonnode=======>"+jsonnode.toString());


        } catch (JSONException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
               //jsonobject = new JSONStringer().object().key("und").array().object().key("value").value(body).endObject().endArray().endObject();

               json = new JSONObject();
               json.put("title",title);
               json.put("body", jsonnode);
               json.put("type","article");

            System.out.println("value of the combine node=======>"+json.toString());   
            //System.out.println("=============>"+jsonobject);

        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("node",json.toString()));
           // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type","page"));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title",title));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body",jsonnode.toString()));

            System.out.println("value of the params =============> "+params);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = null;
        try {
                formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        post.setEntity(formEntity);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("=========> statusCode post idea=====> "+statusCode);    
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                return iStream_to_String(is);
            }
            else
            {
                return "Hello This is status ==> :"+String.valueOf(statusCode);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

     public static String iStream_to_String(InputStream is1) {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1), 4096);
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
        return contentOfMyInputStream;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of custom code you have on your Drupal site, but it's not possible to post to a standard Drupal site outside of the web interface - it's a security measure.

Your best options are:

a: create your own custom API module on the Drupal site and post to that instead (make sure you add some kind of security measures to make sure only your app can post to it)

b: use Android's WebView object to display the Drupal page directly - get users to post to that.

Comment: Heather, have you seen Services? While what is being asked here isn't possible with core, it is using http://dgo.to/services. Here's an Android app that uses it to post stories and blog posts: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/social/drupal-power_hdcc.html

Comment: Ah, had only seen it in passing, and not when I had a use case. Thanks for the heads-up!